# Advanced join three tables Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've got three tables, one containing transport moves between storage and usage location, it has a "from" and "to" uuid, and an 'amount' column. The UUIDs in the "from" and "to" columns refer to a row in one of two tables either the 'storage_location' table or the 'usage_location' table. Now I don't know in which of these two tables the UUID is going to be found

Now I'm trying to transport moves table to either the 'storage_location' table or the 'usage_location' table, so I can match the name and coordinates columns to a transport move. Resulting in something like: amount, to_name, to_coordinates, from_name, from_coordinates

A main problem is that the 'to' and 'from' information can both be in the same 'usage_location' or 'storage_location' tables, but then still need to change the column name based on if it matches the "to" or "from" uuid to either "to_name" or "from_name"

Does anyone have any tips about naming these condionally, or if there's a better way to do this alltogether?

The tables look like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE transport (
    amount double precision NOT NULL,
    timestamp_start timestamp without time zone,
    timestamp_end timestamp without time zone,
    "to" uuid,
    "from" uuid,
    type_water character varying
);

CREATE TABLE location_storage (
    type character varying NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    coordinates double precision[],
    status character varying,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    content_latest double precision,
);

CREATE TABLE location_usage (
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    type character varying,
    coordinates double precision[],
    uuid uuid,
    description text,
    status character varying
);
```

The desired result would be:

Transport table: to (uuid), amount, to_name (either from usage location table or storage location table), to_coordinates: (either from usage location table or storage location table) from (uuid),  from_name (either from usage location table or storage location table), to_coordinates: (either from usage location table or storage location table)

I've tried things like:

```sql
SELECT amount,distance,timestamp_start,type_water,
location_storage.name as to_name, location_storage.type as to_type, location_storage.coordinates as to_coordinates, location_storage.description as to_description, location_storage.status as to_status,
location_usage.name as from_name, location_usage.type as from_type, location_usage.coordinates as from_coordinates,  location_usage.status as from_status
FROM transport
INNER JOIN location_storage ON transport.to = location_storage .uuid OR transport.from = location_storage .uuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN location_usage ON transport.to = location_usage.uuid OR transport.from = location_usage.uuid
```

but this doesn't work if both the transport "from" and "to" uuids are both located in the same location table

**Example Datasets**
transport:

| amount | timestamp_start | timestamp_end | to | from | type_water |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15.1 | 2024-02-16 | 2024-02-16 | UUID_1 | UUID_2 | Dummy |

location_storage:

| type | uuid | coordinates | status | name | content_latest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | UUID_1 | 12323 | Status1 | Name1 | Content_1 |

location_usage:

| name | type | coordinates | uuid | description | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name2 | Type2 | 62562 | UUID_2 | Desc_2 | Status_2 |

Required Result:

| amount | distance | timestamp_start | type_water | to_name | to_type | to_coordinates | to_description | to_status | from_name | from_type | from_coordinates | from_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc | tbc |

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for the tables involved? (in plain text, as an update of your question) Some data would be helpful as well

Comment: I've tried adding some more information, does this help?

Comment: Plain DDL, like `CREATE TABLE ....`, would make it a lot easier

Comment: Also, sample data for the tables involved and the result you want to achieve. Plus the SQL you've managed to write so far on your own. All as editable text, please

Comment: I've added the DDL and added one of my own attempts

Comment: In a CTE, union the two location tables together; if there are columns that are not common between the two tables then either omit them or set a default value for the table that doesn't have the column. Then join your main table to this CTE - which contains all your location UUIDs

Comment: WITH location_table AS (
    select location_storage.coordinates, location_storage.name, location_storage.uuid
    FROM location_storage 
    UNION ALL
    select location_usage.coordinates, location_usage.name, location_usage.uuid
    FROM verbruik
)
SELECT * from transport
INNER JOIN location_table ON transport.to = location_table.uuid OR transport.from = location_table.uuid

I've tried this, but it has the issue of not giving the right result again when both the uuids are in the same table. In that case they'd need to be added twice, one with to_ prefix and once with _from.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve as you haven't provided sample data and the desired result - but I'm guessing you need to join to the CTE twice; once for the "transport.to" and once for the "transport.from" (BTW using reserved words such as "to" and "from" for column names is not a good design decision)

Comment: I've tried adding the desired result in the question, but this is clearly not the format that's expected. Any ideas how I could format my question to improve it?

Comment: Sayar4, I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but it seems like the create statements you provided are maybe pseudo code?  Here's a SQL fiddle with a working create statement as an example.  https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=ff6c9943-f611-4eb2-bd79-cef263d94bf9

Comment: I've updated the question to provide dummy datasets. Please update them to provide enough actual data to illustrate all use cases and then populate the result table with the output you want from your SQL, based on the source data you've provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union the twp location tables and then join `transport` to that union twice.

Try something like this:

```
with locations as (
  select uuid, coordinates, name, 'storage' as location_type
    from location_storage
  union all
  select uuid, coordinates, name, 'usage' as location_type
    from location_usage
)
select dst.uuid as to_uuid, t.amount, dst.name as to_name, 
       dst.coordinates as to_coordinates, src.uuid as from_uuid,
       src.name as from_name, src.coordinates as from_coordinates
  from transport t
       join locations src on src.uuid = t."from"
       join locations dst on dst.uuid = t."to";
```